# log4j not sending INFO mails

Tags: java, email, logging, smtp, log4j

I have a problem : I have the following lo4j.xml and class but I do not find how to configure log4j in order to send mail when there is an INFO log in the class (ERROR mails work).

Here is my log4j.xml :

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="info"/>
        <param name="LevelMax" value="fatal"/>
    </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="mailAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
    <param name="BufferSize" value="1" />
    <param name="SMTPHost" value="xxx" />
    <param name="SMTPPort" value="25" />
    <param name="SMTPUsername" value="xxx@xxx.fr" />
    <param name="SMTPPassword" value="xxx" />
    <param name="From" value="yyyy@yyyy.fr" />
    <param name="To" value="zzzz@zzzz.fr" />
    <param name="Subject" value="[Projet] - Message" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="info" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="info" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="fatal" />
    </filter>
</appender>

<logger name="g.integration.common.Mailer">
    <appender-ref ref="mailAppender" />
</logger>

<root>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

And the class :

```
public class Mailer {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Mailer.class);
    private static final String MAIL_INFO_MESSAGE = "Bonjour,\nLe traitement suivant s'est déroulé avec succès :\n";
    private static final String MAIL_ERROR_MESSAGE = "Bonjour,\nUne erreur est survenue lors du traitement MGAS"
            + "\nVoici la trace de l'erreur relevée :\n\n";

    /**
     * Envoie un mail d'information
     * 
     * @param mailString
     */
    public void logSuccessMail(final String mailString) {
        logger.info(MAIL_INFO_MESSAGE + mailString);
    }

    /**
     * Envoie un mail d'erreur
     * 
     * @param mailString
     */
    public void logErrorMail(final String mailString) {
        logger.error(MAIL_ERROR_MESSAGE + mailString);
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea?
Thanks in advance and sorry for the formatting.. I will correct it when I will find how

Answer (score 0):

The SMTPAppender by design only logs ERROR and above messages.

> By default, an email message will be sent when an ERROR or higher
>   severity message is appended. The triggering criteria can be modified
>   by setting the evaluatorClass property with the name of a class
>   implementing TriggeringEventEvaluator, setting the evaluator property
>   with an instance of TriggeringEventEvaluator or nesting a
>   triggeringPolicy element where the specified class implements
>   TriggeringEventEvaluator.

Setting threshold doesn't work. You need to have a custom implementation of [TriggeringEventEvaluator](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/TriggeringEventEvaluator.html). The below code works.

```
<appender name="mailAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
    <param name="BufferSize" value="1" />
    <param name="SMTPHost" value="xxx" />
    <param name="SMTPPort" value="25" />
    <param name="SMTPUsername" value="xxx@xxx.fr" />
    <param name="SMTPPassword" value="xxx" />
    <param name="From" value="yyyy@yyyy.fr" />
    <param name="To" value="zzzz@zzzz.fr" />
    <param name="Subject" value="[Projet] - Message" />
    <param name="evaluatorClass" value="myapp.EmailTriggerEvaluator"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
    </layout>        
</appender>


public class EmailTriggerEvaluator implements TriggeringEventEvaluator {
    @Override
    public boolean isTriggeringEvent(LoggingEvent event) {
        return event.getLevel().isGreaterOrEqual(Level.INFO);
    }
}
```